# upload multiple file_name in db

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, upload

Hi i want to upload multiple file and store multiple file_name in db.
it is uploading file correctly but not storing multiple file_name in one column,
e.g. if i am uploading two files so it is storing two files name in two new column, but i want to store both in same column.

**Note:**
this is the code which i am using to upload file_name

```
foreach($filepath as $a) {
            $a['file_name'].=",";
            echo $a['file_name'];
$db_data = array('pic_id'=> NULL,
'ad_pic'=> $a['file_name']);
$this->db->insert('pics',$db_data);
    }
```

**My Controller**

```
<?php

class upload extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->view("main_temp/header.php");
       $this->load->view('first_body');
        $this->load->view("main_temp/footer.php");
    }

// controller
function do_upload()
{
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '100';
    $config['max_width']  = '1024';
    $config['max_height']  = '768';
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);


    if($this->input->post('submit'))
    {
         $path = './uploads';
        if($this->upload->do_multi_upload("myfile")){
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($this->upload->get_multi_upload_data());
            echo '</pre>';


        $this->load->model('mypost');
        $this->mypost->post();
      }
    }else{
        $this->load->view("main_temp/header.php");
        $this->load->view('upload_f');
        $this->load->view("main_temp/footer.php");
    }
    }

    }

?>
```

**MY Model**

```
<?php
class mypost extends CI_Model
{

    function post()
    { 
        $filepath =$this->upload->get_multi_upload_data('file_name'); 

foreach($filepath as $a) {
            $a['file_name'].=",";
            echo $a['file_name'];
$db_data = array('pic_id'=> NULL,
'ad_pic'=> $a['file_name']);
$this->db->insert('pics',$db_data);
    }
        $title=$_POST['title'];
        $description=$_POST['description'];

        $category=$_POST['category'];
        $this->db->trans_begin();

        $this->db->query("insert into post (title,detail)
         values ('$title','$description')");


        $ad_id = $this->db->insert_id();

        $this->db->query("insert into category (cat_type,post_id_fk)
 values ('$category', $ad_id)");

        if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE)
        {
            $this->db->trans_rollback();
        }
        else
        {
      //  echo "<h1> Hurrah! </h1> <br> Data has been saved";
            $this->db->trans_commit();
        }
    }

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `$this->upload->get_multi_upload_data('file_name')` returns an array, the reason it's creating multiple rows in the database is because you run `$this->db->insert('pics', $db_data);` for each file name returned.

Instead, try saving your data to a variable established outside the `foreach` loop, and posting it to the db after the loop has completed, thusly:

```
$filepath = $this->upload->get_multi_upload_data('file_name'); 

$filenames = ''

foreach($filepath as $a) {
    $filenames .= $a['file_name'].",";
}
$filenames = rtrim($filenames,',');


$db_data = array(
    'pic_id'=> NULL,
    'ad_pic'=> $filenames
);
$this->db->insert('pics', $db_data);
```

Comment: Thank u so so so so so so much.

Comment: there is a little bit problem are you there?

Comment: Still here - ask away!

Answer (score 0):

I have make little change in existing code to get file name filename1,filename1, to filename1,filename2

```
foreach($filepath as $a) {
    $filenames .= $a['file_name'].",";
}
$filenames = rtrim($filenames,','); // I have make changes here
```

This code will removing unnecessary (comma) at the end of filename string.